# Implicit and explicit cast

Tags: c#

is this possible?

```
string wellFormattedGuidAsString = ...;
Guid guid = wellFormattedGuidAsString;

...
Method(wellFormattedGuidAsString ); 
void Method(Guid id) { ... }
```

I tried with explicit and implicit cast.

```
public static implicit operator Guid(string str)
{
    Guid guid;
    Guid.TryParse(str, out guid);
    return guid;
}
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: You tried and.... what happened?

Comment: You can't overload operators for existing .net types, you could provide an extension method that converts `string` to `Guid`.

Comment: explicit/implicit keyword declares a user-defined type conversion operator

Comment: Yeah I know that  I can make extension method for this but I really want do it Guid guid = guidString.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create implicit and explicit operators outside of the desired object.

What you can do instead is :

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static Guid ToGuid(this string str) 
    {
        Guid guid;
        Guid.TryParse(str, out guid);
        return guid;
    }
}
```

And later on  you can use it like :

```
string mestring = " ... ";
Guid guid = mestring.ToGuid();
```

**EDIT:**

There's another way (of course there is) which is a bit useless but I'll post it here :

Make a class that will wrap `string`

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    string _string;

    public StringWrapper(string str)
    {
        _string = str;
    }

    public static implicit StringWrapper operator(string str)
    {
        return new StringWrapper(str);
    }

    public static implicit string operator(StringWrapper strWrapper)
    {
        return strWrapper._string;
    }

    public static implicit Guid operator(StringWrapper strWrapper)
    {
        Guid guid;
        Guid.TryParse(str, out guid);
        return guid;
    }

    public static implicit StringWrapper operator(Guid guid)
    {
        return guid.ToString();
    }
}
```

And this useless class let's you do something like this:

```
string str = "..";
Guid guid = (StringWrapper)str;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just overload your method:

```
void Method(Guid id) { ... } 
void Method(string guid) {
    Guid _guid;
    Guid.TryParse(guid, out _guid);
    Method(_guid);
}
```